# How to improve the performance of svm by using fuzzy membership function in R?

Tags: r, svm, outliers, accuracy, fuzzy

According to [Lin and Wang, 2002](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/991432), fuzzy support vector machine gives good performance on reducing the effects of outliers and significantly improves the classification accuracy and generalization.

Given the sequence of training points ‎$X‎‎_{i}$ and ‎$‎y_{i} \in ‎\lbrace -1, +1‎\rbrace‎‎‎$‎ represents its class label‎, denote the mean of class ‎$‎C_{+}‎$‎ and class $‎C_{-}‎$ as $X_{+}‎$ and $X_{-}‎$, respectively.\
The radius of class $‎C_{+}‎$ is ‎$‎‎r_{+}=max‎\parallel X_{+}-X‎_{i}‎\parallel$‎  where $X_{+} \in ‎C_{+}‎$;and the radius of class $‎C_{-}‎$ is ‎$‎‎r_{-}=max‎\parallel X_{-}-X‎_{i}‎\parallel$‎  where $X_{-} \in ‎C_{-}‎$;
The fuzzy membership  ‎$‎s_{i}=0‎$ is

‎‎[  s_{i}= \left{‎‎
\begin{array}{ll}‎
      1-‎\parallel X_{+}-X‎_{i}‎\parallel/r_{+}+‎\delta‎‎‎‎ &‎ ~ ~ ‎\mbox{if}‎ ~ ~ X_{i} \in C_{+} \\‎
      1-‎\parallel X_{-}-X‎_{i}‎\parallel/r_{-}+‎\delta‎‎‎‎ &‎ ~ ~ ‎\mbox{if}‎ ~ ~ X_{i} \in C_{-} \\‎
   ‎\end{array}‎
‎\right‎. ‎]‎‎

where ‎$‎\delta>0‎$‎ is a constant to avoid the case ‎$‎s_{i}=0‎$‎.‎‎

**The problem I've faced is that,  the accuracy of fuzzy svm is not higher than the classical SVM, in the presence of outliers.**  The following code is the written R codes based on the FSVM. I will be appreciated if someone can guide me on that. Thanks in advance.

```
mysvm<-function(X,y,cost){
library(kernlab)
#----------------------------------------------------#
# Optimization uing ipop() function of kernlab package
#----------------------------------------------------#
n <- dim(X)[1]
# build the system matrices
Q <- sapply(1:n, function(i) y[i]*t(X)[,i])
D <- t(Q)%*%Q
d <- matrix(1, nrow=n)

uu <- cost   
eps <- 1e-2    
b <- 0
r <- 0
A2 <- t(y)
l <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=1)
u <- matrix(uu, nrow=n, ncol=1)

capture.output(sol <- ipop(-d, t(Q)%*%Q+eps*diag(n), A2, b, l, u, 
r,verb=TRUE, sigf=5, margin=1e-8))
ipopsol <- primal(sol)
alpha<- matrix(ipopsol , nrow=n)

#--------------------------------------------------#
# Calculation of the normal vector W and bias term b
#--------------------------------------------------#

w=t(alpha*y)%*%(X) #W
ff=matrix(rep(alpha*y,n),n,n)*X%*%t(X)
fout=matrix(t(apply(ff,2,sum)))
pos=which(alpha>1e-6)
b = mean(y[pos]-fout[pos]) #b
fx=t(w %*% t(as.matrix(X))) + b 

#-----------------------------#
#    SVM line & support vectors
#-----------------------------#

plot(X,pch=ifelse(y==1, 1, 3),col=ifelse(y==1, 1, 2))
abline(a=-b/w[1,2], b=-w[1,1]/w[1,2], col="black", lty=1)
abline(a=-(b+1)/w[1,2], b=-w[1,1]/w[1,2], col="orange", lty=3)
abline(a=-(b-1)/w[1,2], b=-w[1,1]/w[1,2], col="orange", lty=3)
points(X[pos,],col="blue",cex=2) # show the support vectors


#------------------#
#    ACCURACY
#------------------#

pred<-function(x,lable){
C=NULL
for (i in 1:length(x)){
if(x[i]>0){C[i]=1}
else {C[i]=-1}
}
accuracy=mean(C==lable)
result=list(C,accuracy)
return(accuracy)
}
pred(fx,y)
}
#------------------#
#       DATA
#------------------#

library(MASS)
set.seed(44)#44

groupN=mvrnorm(20,c(rep(-2,2)),diag(c(rep(1,2))))
groupP=mvrnorm(20,c(rep(2,2)),diag(c(rep(1,2))))
X=rbind(groupN,groupP)
y<-rep(c(-1,1),each=20)
a1=c(0,0);a2=c(0,-1);a3=c(-1,-1);a4=c(1,0)
X=rbind(X,a1,a2,a3,a4)
y=c(y,1,1,1,-1)
mysvm(X,y,10)
```

The calculated accuracy for classical SVM is 0.9545455. I have computed the membership function according to this codes,

```
#------------------#
#    FUZZY SVM
#------------------#

Si<-function(x,y,delta){
Pxbar<-apply(groupP,2,mean)
Nxbar<-apply(groupN,2,mean)
S=NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
 for (j in 1:ncol(x)){
if (y[i]==1)
{S[i]=1-sqrt(sum((Pxbar[j]-x[i,j])^2))/(max(sqrt(sum((Pxbar[j]-x[i ,j])^2)
))+delta)}
else
{S[i]=1-sqrt(sum((Nxbar[j]-x[i,j])^2))/(max(sqrt(sum((Nxbar[j]
- x[i,j])^2)))+delta)}
}}
return(S)
}
mysvm(X,y,10*Si(X,y,0.5))
```

The calculated accuracy for classical SVM is  0.9318182. The following pictures are respectively the classical and fuzzified SVM.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you calculating accuracy? On your training sample or with a hold-out test set? Overfitting will give greater accuracy on the training set.

Comment: @Wayne I've computed the accuracy of both methods (SVM and FSVM) on the training sample. But  FSVM supposed to give higher accuracy, while with the above codes, the FSVM accuracy is lower than the classical SVM.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, you say you're looking at accuracy on the training sample. This will mislead you. You need to measure on a hold-out test set (or do cross-validation, etc). Being more accurate on the training sample can be very misleading, since it may be due to overfitting, which will cause problems outside of the training set. ("Generalization" has to do with data not in the training set.) And the bottom line is if your training is going to be less sensitive to outliers, it's going to be less accurate on outliers -- perhaps way less "accurate".

Second, you say "accuracy" and by that I assume you mean Accuracy as in % categorized correctly. But in most real problems, you should be concerned about other measures such as Precision or Recall.

Comment: I used the simulated data, so even for the simulated data I suppose to use  the test set?

Comment: If you used all of your simulated data to train the model, and then looked at how it predicted on the same data, yes you can be misled. If you can simulate another set of data and test on that -- obviously you need to make sure random seeds aren't set the same, etc -- you should see a difference where the fuzzy SVM generalizes better and gives you better results.

Comment: @ Wayne Just to check with you;  whether I understand you correctly or not.! I should generate test set data with different seed and also their labels. Then by using the computed _"w"_ and _"b"_ from the train set, the classifying function "f(x)=w*x+b" can be computed (here "x" is the test set data) . Finally the accuracy can be computed based on the test set and its known label. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Sounds right. You calculate your coefficients on the training set, then test them on a separate test set of data. (There are fancier methods like Cross-Validation, etc, but this is the simplest.) Then check accuracy. But you should also look at the entire Confusion Matrix and also think about how your algorithm will be used: Accuracy is not always the best measure of "accuracy".

Comment: But I'm not able to find the link between this **And the bottom line is if your training is going to be less sensitive to outliers, it's going to be less accurate on outliers -- perhaps way less "accurate".** and the claim of the fuzzy svm.

Comment: I compute the accuracy according to the output of confusion matrix. You mean instead of accuracy I should compute recall or precision?

Comment: @user2802663: Precision is more important than Accuracy for some tasks. (Ones I often work on.) Just saying you should measure the accuracy of the two results with the metric you'd use in your application. It may be Accuracy, but maybe not. Sounds like you're familiar with the issues.

Comment: @ Wayne: As you said there is two way to measure the accuracy, which cross validation is one of them. Can you tell me how can I do cross validation, without using the built in function of R like tune()? since I have not use the svm() of e1071 package.